# securing .svc webservice with a x509 certificate

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I have a .svc web service hosted on my server we are using behavior low as a test to make sure that the webservice caller get what they are supposed to get.
now I want to use x509 certificate, I have the certificate and need to send it to the consumer so that they can double check if it is possible to exchange data.
I am not sure which steps to follow 
I have these two documentation but I want to double check with anyone who knows how this can be done better.

[steps to enable x509](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF)

[Pattern and practice WCF](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ch%2013%20-%20Internet%20%E2%80%93%20WCF%20and%20ASMX%20Client%20to%20Remote%20WCF%20Using%20Transport%20Security%20%28Trusted%20Subsystem%2C%20HTTP%29&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: and what are the reasons to close the question? you don't understand it, don't have any idea, this is ridiculous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use x509 certificate to authenticate clients that call your WCF service, then the first article you referenced is a pretty good step-by-step guide. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF
This article assumes that both your client and service run on the same machine, so you will need to adjust instructions for your specific case.

Step 1: Create client and server certificates

Since you already have the certificates, you may skip this step. You would have to replace WcfServer and WcfClient with the names from your server and client certificates in steps 3 and 7.

Step 2: Copy the certificates in trusted people certificates

The referenced article explains how to open Certificates snap-in in MMC. Since you are using your existing certificates, you may need to import your service certificate on the server and client certificate on the client machine. Then export client certificate without private key and import it into Trusted People folder on the server machine.

Step 3: Specify the certificate in the WCF service web.config file

```
<serviceCredentials>
  <clientCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
  </clientCertificate>
  <serviceCertificate findValue="!Insert name from your server certificate here!"
     storeLocation="LocalMachine"
     storeName="My"
     x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
```

Step 4: Define binding in the WCF service web.config file

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
    <binding>
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Step 5: Tie up the bindings with the end point in the WCF service web.config file

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
   bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="WCFServiceCertificate.IService1">
```

Step 6: Make your web application client for consuming the WCF service.

When you add a service reference, Visual Studio inserts  element in the client web.config file. You will need to modify it as in steps 7 and 8.

Step 7: Define certificate for WCF client in the client web.config file

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="!Insert name from your client certificate here!"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
            storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
      <serviceCertificate>
         <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
      </serviceCertificate>
   </clientCredentials>
 </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Step 8: Tie up the behavior with the end point on WCF client in the client web.config file

You would need to replace address, contract and dns value to match your actual WCF service.

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1387/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
    <identity>
      <dns value="WcfServer" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: thanks that is the same article that I had but wasn't sure if it is applicable